# getElementById doesn't work in a simple case

Tags: html

I don't understand why this isn't working on my website :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="2" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="button" value="Multiply by 2" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(‘input1’).value=document.getElementById(‘input1’).value*2;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

A string delimiter can be:

- '
- "

You cannot use the symbol ***‘***

Example:

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" value="2" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="button" value="Multiply by 2" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('input1').value=document.getElementById('input1').value*2;" />
```

A new example:

```js
function multiply2() {
  document.getElementById('input1').value = +document.getElementById('input1').value * 2;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" value="2" readonly="readonly"/>
<input type="button" value="Multiply by 2" onclick="multiply2()"/>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="2" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="button" value="Multiply by 2" onclick="multiply2()" />

<script type="text/javascript>
  function multiply2(){
  document.getElementById('input1').value=document.getElementById('input1').value*2;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @LoïcKreseski You have some strange chars inside ​ getElementById and *2. Please, use a standard ascii editor.

Comment: @LoïcKreseski You may see these chars, for instance, using the browser debug tool usually attached to the F12 key.